# Eat more or less to lose fat and gain muscle

Tags: weight-loss, diet, muscle, vegetarian

I am working to get my six packs and as per the saying "it starts from kitchen", so I started looking into diet plans on Google. Amazing to know that different sites have different diet plans.

One [site](http://www.weighttraining.com/blog/wanna-get-6-pack-abs-fast) claims, that eggs, whey protein, and boiled vegetables are enough.

While another [site](http://bodyforlife.com/library/articles/training/12-deadly-workout-sins) claims:

> But if you don’t eat enough during the day, your body goes into starvation mode and slows down its metabolism, making it even harder to lose weight.

I am confused which diet plan is good to lose fat as well help me to sync up with my gym workout to gain muscle.

So, what is the correct diet to reduce fat and gain muscle?

- Eat less and concentrate more on protein (as per site link 1)
- Eat enough so that body metabolism can work properly ( as per site link 2)

**Info**

*I am adding the below section, if someone can help me identify the right plan for me*
I am a vegetarian, I am open for vegetables, fruits and dairy products. but not to eggs [reason: **it is not vegetarian** - from my [previous question]](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/9621/white-eggs-can-be-considered-as-non-vegetarian)

Comment: I don't want to spoil it for you, but dairy products are not vegetarian and so are whey supplements. Cheese contains rennet (made from calves), cows needs to have a calf around 1 time a year to keep the milk flow going (those calves get disposed) and one out of two potential new milk cows is a bull (that gets disposed). As a vegetarian myself, I just try to use dairy and egg products responsible: buy biological if available and do not overuse them (ie drench everything with cheese).

Comment: In my country dairy products are counted as purely vegetarian.

Comment: If you are interested in diet, please commit to this site:  http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/44550/nutrition

Comment: `protein rich foods : these are protein content in gms per one kg.... ` milk - 33 
panner - 110 

bengal gram - 190
green gram - 240

black beans - 210
kidney beans - 240 
soybean - 360 

fenugreek [ menthe ] - 230

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hi Zerotoinfinite,

Look at this picture

[image]

As you can see in the picture, the biggest contributor to gaining six pack is **lower body fat percentages**. As you can see, the six pack becomes more visible as the body fat percentage reduces.

So, reduce your body fat percentage and your six pack will become visible.

With regards to your specific question about *eating less and concentrating on protein* or *eating enough so that the body metabolism can function*, here's my opinion:

- **Eat enough so that your body metabolism can function**; you'll not get your six pack if your body metabolism cannot function properly. You won't have the energy and strength for the exercises required to torch your body fat. Because of lack of energy, you're likely to feel miserable, which will further reduce your energy levels. Basically, it's a lose-lose situation for you.
- Your calorie consumption should depend on mainly two things: your BMR and daily activities. If your daily activity is very small, the recommended calorie intake revolves around the BMR calorie burn; if your daily activity is very high, your calorie consumption requirement will be high as well.
- Regarding the first article, the guy worked with a professional trainer *(who gave him the diet needed to achieve his goal within that time frame)*. Also, although he didn't eat much regular food, he took lots of supplements and multivitamins, which acts like food. *If you've taken any of the protein supplements before, you'll realize that they fill you up like regular food; the only difference being it's packed with protein-based nutrients more than most foods.* So, if you add up all his food intake, you'll realize that he wasn't depriving his body of food. That's why he could have the energy to perform all the required exercises he needed to complete.

While the Internet is packed with specific food items for anyone to consume, your primary food intake will contain both ***protein and fiber***.

In summary, both sites tell you to consume enough calories for your body to function. Fat loss *(and ultimately six pack)* is impossible if you don't have the energy to exercise.

Answer (score 3):

- Eating *less* will leave you malnourished, lacking vitamins and essential minerals et cetera.
- Eating *more* will leave you over nourished, extra fat, insulin spikes et cetera.
- Eating in *moderate* proportions is what every human should aim for.
- ["Too much of anything is bad for you."](http://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/cutting-edge-leadership/201302/too-much-anything-is-bad-you)

I know the link I have refereed to you is not fitness/strength based. I like to view things differently. I feel focusing on a balanced diet where you consume foods in moderate proportions leads to a healthier and better life. The same goes for work, life, relationships and training to become a stronger you..

If you are training to get a "six pack" then I'm you will get what you want if you stay consistent and work hard. But ask yourself what happens when you get the six pack? Do you return to your old eating habits? Do you stop training?

Fitness is a lifestyle, not a quick fix.

[ 1 ] Statements made are based on personal experience and extensive research, that is still ongoing, trying to figure out if diets truly work.

[ Edit ] I saw that you stated that you are a vegetarian. There are plenty of good resources online that talk about dieting.Most of the things you ask, may have already been asked and answered by somebody else. Spend time searching on Google and this board to avoid duplicating questions. An example of a popular fitness individual [Frank Medrano](http://www.thefrankmedrano.com/) is vegan.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that you can gain muscle and at the same time you lose fat.To gain muscle you have to gain some fat,but if you are already fat then you just loose your weight and gain muscle.Eating less and loosing fat and gaining muscle is not the proper way of making the physic.If you eat less than its very dangerous for your body,your body have to suffer from lack of vitamins,proteins and minerals.Eat everything but don't eat junk and oily food it will raise your weight.Eat the diet full of proteins,minerals and carbohydrate.Body metabolism can function properly only if you eat enough.

Comment: It is a bit difficult to follow the logic in your answer, perhaps you can add more structure to it.

Answer (score 1):

After doing this for a while, I learned that it comes down to the calories. Its pretty simple when you think about it. All calories are is energy. If you take in more energy than you body expends, you gain weight. If you take in less energy than your body expends, you lose weight. As long as you are in a calorie deficit, you will lose weight. I guarantee it :) Now for the meal plan part, you can eat whatever you want as long as you keep yourself in a caloric deficit. If you want to stick to a vegetarian diet, then take a look at this link:

http://www.mayoclinic.org/healthy-living/nutrition-and-healthy-eating/in-depth/vegetarian-diet/art-20046446

The most important part of any diet is the micro nutrients. Being deficient in any important micro nutrients can and will be detrimental to your health! Supplements can be useful, but they will never EVER be a meal replacement. So don't over do it! Try to get your nutrition as much as possible from whole, nutrient dense, foods.

The entire idea of a metabolism slow down is rubbish. Check any credible study done on it and you will see for yourself. It is promoted by the supplement industry so that you can buy more products since we all know bodybuilders will buy ANYTHING. There is no magical weight loss food, no herb that can help you sweat it all out or something like that. Any product you see online or on tv that claims you will lose weight is garbage. The trick is simply hard work. Stay active, track your progress and be persistent. The results will follow :)

Good luck!

Comment: Given you mention credible studies, it would benefit your answer if you could provide some to substantiate your claims

Comment: Starvation mode is a myth, however metabolic slowdown is a proven fact. I find it odd that people will accept that exercise increases your metabolism, yet refuse to acknowledge that lack of exercise will result in a slower metabolism.

Comment: Doesn't really matter, the decrease/increase in the metabolism looked at either view point does not make a significant difference vs the reduction in energy due to simple calorie reduction.

Comment: @IvoFlipse didn't think it was too hard to go on google scholar and search "calorie metabolic rate" ;)

http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1038/oby.2007.354/full